# How can I position a long equation centered/on top of a page?

Tags: equations, positioning, kbordermatrix

I am using kbordermatrix to display data in my appendix, they are wrapped in equations.

As only one of these matrices seem to fit per page and they are positioned at the bottom of the pages, I have several pages with are empty at their top half. I wondered if there is a **way to either put them on top or at least centered**.

Here is one of the tables as example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}% Left delimiter
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}% Right delimiter
DPWM_{Zld\_rep 2} = \kbordermatrix{
    &pos\,1&pos\,2&pos\,3&pos\,4&pos\,5&pos\,6 \\
    AA & 4.98e-2 &3.62e-3 &1.31e-3 &1.52e-3 &1.37e-2 &1.37e-1\\
    AC & 1.62e-2 &9.04e-3 &1.37e-3 &3.34e-4 &1.74e-2 &1.67e-1\\
    AG & 3.42e-2 &7.32e-1 &4.58e-3 &1.72e-5 &6.45e-3 &2.21e-1\\
    AT & 1.79e-2 &1.58e-2 &1.83e-4 &1.97e-3 &1.34e-2 &9.28e-2\\
    CA & 3.38e-1 &4.73e-3 &8.41e-3 &7.04e-6 &6.64e-2 &4.91e-2\\
    CC & 2.13e-2 &3.91e-3 &2.04e-2 &1.17e-2 &5.48e-2 &3.89e-2\\
    CG & 3.50e-2 &4.62e-2 &1.14e-2 &1.66e-5 &3.47e-2 &3.80e-2\\
    CT & 3.93e-2 &4.38e-3 &4.35e-4 &1.88e-3 &4.88e-2 &4.16e-2\\
    GA & 6.34e-2 &2.69e-3 &2.32e-3 &2.30e-2 &3.41e-2 &1.79e-2\\
    GC & 2.66e-2 &1.56e-3 &2.21e-3 &1.12e-1 &3.05e-2 &4.14e-2\\
    GG & 3.39e-2 &7.59e-2 &9.27e-1 &5.75e-2 &1.49e-2 &2.34e-2\\
    GT & 2.50e-2 &4.63e-3 &3.90e-4 &7.89e-1 &2.21e-2 &2.96e-2\\
    TA & 2.16e-1 &5.47e-3 &1.26e-5 &1.25e-6 &4.67e-1 &2.67e-2\\
    TC & 2.09e-2 &1.62e-3 &1.14e-5 &9.06e-4 &8.05e-2 &2.85e-2\\
    TG & 2.66e-2 &8.53e-2 &2.00e-2 &9.71e-6 &4.96e-2 &2.13e-2\\
    TT & 3.59e-2 &3.29e-3 &4.07e-6 &3.32e-4 &4.52e-2 &2.58e-2\\
}
\end{equation}
```

Here is how it looks at the moment:
[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question accordingly

Comment: Try `\raggedbottom` at the start of that chapter.

Comment: @Tiuri that moved to to the top, very cool! Is there also a comparable function to put it central? if not, post it as an answer!

Comment: Not in a similar way, AFAIK. To have it centered on a page, I would rather put each equation in a `figure` environment with the `p!` placement option.

Comment: Just put the whole equation inside a {table}[t] environment… You just need to be careful about the correct numbering when an equation further down your source code is placed before your page break in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the first equation not at the bottom of an empty page, you can add `\raggedbottom` to the specific chapter which disables the automatic vertical distribution of content on the page (which leads to this behaviour). To change back to the default setting for later chapters, use `\flushbottom`.

To have an equation vertically centered on its own page, I would suggest to put the equation inside a `figure` environment (or other float) with the `p!` positioning option.

The following example demonstrates the two possibilities:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\myarray}{\begin{array}{ccccccc}
    &pos\,1&pos\,2&pos\,3&pos\,4&pos\,5&pos\,6 \\
    AA & 4.98e-2 &3.62e-3 &1.31e-3 &1.52e-3 &1.37e-2 &1.37e-1\\
    AC & 1.62e-2 &9.04e-3 &1.37e-3 &3.34e-4 &1.74e-2 &1.67e-1\\
    AG & 3.42e-2 &7.32e-1 &4.58e-3 &1.72e-5 &6.45e-3 &2.21e-1\\
    AT & 1.79e-2 &1.58e-2 &1.83e-4 &1.97e-3 &1.34e-2 &9.28e-2\\
    CA & 3.38e-1 &4.73e-3 &8.41e-3 &7.04e-6 &6.64e-2 &4.91e-2\\
    CC & 2.13e-2 &3.91e-3 &2.04e-2 &1.17e-2 &5.48e-2 &3.89e-2\\
    CG & 3.50e-2 &4.62e-2 &1.14e-2 &1.66e-5 &3.47e-2 &3.80e-2\\
    CT & 3.93e-2 &4.38e-3 &4.35e-4 &1.88e-3 &4.88e-2 &4.16e-2\\
    GA & 6.34e-2 &2.69e-3 &2.32e-3 &2.30e-2 &3.41e-2 &1.79e-2\\
    GC & 2.66e-2 &1.56e-3 &2.21e-3 &1.12e-1 &3.05e-2 &4.14e-2\\
    GG & 3.39e-2 &7.59e-2 &9.27e-1 &5.75e-2 &1.49e-2 &2.34e-2\\
    GT & 2.50e-2 &4.63e-3 &3.90e-4 &7.89e-1 &2.21e-2 &2.96e-2\\
    TA & 2.16e-1 &5.47e-3 &1.26e-5 &1.25e-6 &4.67e-1 &2.67e-2\\
    TC & 2.09e-2 &1.62e-3 &1.14e-5 &9.06e-4 &8.05e-2 &2.85e-2\\
    TG & 2.66e-2 &8.53e-2 &2.00e-2 &9.71e-6 &4.96e-2 &2.13e-2\\
    TT & 3.59e-2 &3.29e-3 &4.07e-6 &3.32e-4 &4.52e-2 &2.58e-2\\
    GT & 2.50e-2 &4.63e-3 &3.90e-4 &7.89e-1 &2.21e-2 &2.96e-2\\
    TA & 2.16e-1 &5.47e-3 &1.26e-5 &1.25e-6 &4.67e-1 &2.67e-2\\
    TC & 2.09e-2 &1.62e-3 &1.14e-5 &9.06e-4 &8.05e-2 &2.85e-2\\
    TG & 2.66e-2 &8.53e-2 &2.00e-2 &9.71e-6 &4.96e-2 &2.13e-2\\
    TT & 3.59e-2 &3.29e-3 &4.07e-6 &3.32e-4 &4.52e-2 &2.58e-2\\
\end{array}}
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\begin{equation}
A=\myarray
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A=\myarray
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[!p]
\begin{equation}
A=\myarray
\end{equation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: You might consider creating a new float class using newfloat (or float, if you don't mind the side effects).  That way you can add captions and have a list of matrices.